# WPF ListBox Commands within ListBoxItem MVVM Command Binding

Tags: wpf, mvvm, listbox, datacontext, icommand

I have been trying to find a way to have command buttons within my **ListBoxItem's** of a **ListBox** control. I use ***MVVM and Command Binding to the DataContext via ICommand interface***. I am unable to find a way to bind to the Views DataContext from *within the ListBox ItemsSource*. I continue to get a **Command *"Not Found"* error**. Can anyone help me understand how to accomplish this. I believe that it has something to do with the command binding path, but I am unsure. Any help or direction would be great.

Comment: It would be good if you provide code that produces the error. Can you also provide your ListBox code and ListBoxItem template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DataContext` of items in a `ListBox` will be the item they represent. So if your `ItemsSource` is bound to a list of Widgets, then the `DataContext` of your `ListBoxItem` will be a Widget.

If you need to access the `DataContext` of the `ListBox`, rather than the `ListBoxItem`, then you can use `RelativeSource`:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}},
                                  Path=DataContext.MyCommand}" />
```

Comment: I need to access the DataContext of the WPF Window itself, so do I need to go up one more level or would your response be high enough in the tree?

Comment: Thank you... I answered my own question. "Type Window". Thanks for your help.